# Volume, Panning, and Multiple Processes of Android's MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio

I had three tasks I wanted to do:
1. Get multiple mediaplayer's running different audio streams.
2. Change the volume of these audio streams.
3. Change the left and right ear volume's independently (i.e., panning)

After searching around for a while, I found no satisfactory answer.

For 1., most people suggested using SoundPool (my original intuition) or AudioTrack's (the latter of which is a bloody nightmare since it means one basically has to build a whole new mediaplayer).

For 2., everyone seemed to have a spaz and keep talking about AudioManager, which is literally a different problem (in most of the contexts I saw, including mine). It also cannot deal with 3.

For 3., I found almost nothing with occasional reference to AudioTrack's.

Well, I came up with an incredibly simple solution, which I figured would be useful to put up here.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is that you can use multiple MediaPlayer's with independent left/right volumes for each track using .setVolume(left, right). However, and this is **absolutely crucial**...

It will **not** work with all audio formats. At present, I have got .wav files to work completely while .mp3's will not work (in any of the 3 respects).

I hope this saves some of you some of the time I just wasted accidentally coming up with a solution.

As a caveat, this worked on a Nexus 5 running API 23, so I can make no promises for other contexts.